What do you call polynomials of this type?
I came across this simple type of polynomial, where each term is the derivative of the previous one, e.g.:
$$
f(x)=x^4+4x^3+12x^2+24x+24
$$
So that the derivative of the whole polynomial is trivial, just removing the first term:
$$
f'(x)=4x^3+12x^2+24x+24
$$
This seems relatively simple, so I was just wondering if there's a name for these polynomials?

Hint:  Consider the Taylor polynomials for $e^x$.

This can also be formulated in an ODE $f(x)-f'(x)=x^n$, maybe there is a name for this .

They're multiples of Maclaurin polynomials of $e^x$. I don't know if there's a better description than that.

You can find them all solving this equation $$f(x) = x^n+f'(x)$$
So you have $$f'(x) = nx^{n-1}+f''(x)$$
$$f''(x) = n(n-1)x^{n-2}+f'''(x)$$
$$\vdots $$
So $$f(x) = x^n + nx^{n-1}+n(n-1)x^{n-2} + n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}+...$$

As said in comments
$$f(x)-f'(x)=x^n$$
$$f(x)=e^x \,g(x) \quad \implies \quad g'(x)=-x^n \,e^{-x}$$
$$g(x)=-\int x^n \,e^{-x}\,dx=\Gamma (n+1,x)+C$$
$$f(x)=e^x\Big(\Gamma (n+1,x)+C\Big)$$
